# How to access query string parameters to perform a search/filtering on API using HAPI JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, hapi.js

I am developing an API which can search the API with the given keyword in the query string parameter using HAPI JS.

For example: localhost:8000/api?search={GivenKeyWord}

Could anyone please suggest how to implement this in HAPI JS? I am using MYSQL as the Database

Answer (score 4):

A code snippet of what you tried would help answer you question better. However since you mentioned you use hapi, in your handler function for this specific route you can access the query parameters with `request.query`, which is an object with the query parameters name as keys with their values as their value. 
For what you are asking, you would probably need something like that:

```
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/api",
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      var searchQuery = request.query.search;
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello @DSCH, I would like to do something like this : server.route({
    method : 'GET',
    path: '/api',
    handler: function(request, reply){
        const query = request.query;
        Perform search on API using MYSQL Database 
        reply(query);
    }
});

Comment: The `request.query` is an object contain all the query params and their values. so your search query, according to the url you provided in your question will be in `request.query.seach`. With that you can do whatever you want with your database.

Comment: Could you please write a sample code on making a Database call for querystring from our discussion. That would help me to understand the concept.

Comment: I don't know if you have a database already and if you managed to connect it to you node.js server. Anyway you can try this simple tutorial and put the pieces you need from it in your api: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp  If you then keep having issues or question, kindly post what you tried and maybe others or me can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/api",
    handler:(request, reply) => {
      let {search} = request.query;

      console.log('Search param = ',search)

    }
})
```

I would use ES6 destructuring assignment to simplify